# Tkinter module not recognized

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, pip, python-module

Hello I have a problem in Python 3 on Windows with the Tkinter module it is not recognized when I import it even though I installed it on PowerShell with pip.
I don't know if the module is not installed or if I enter the correct code, don't hesitate to show me how to use Tkinter.

Comment: Did you try `import tkinter` or `import Tkinter`?

Comment: This is a very small detail, but I suggest that English version of title should come first, and french translation (if really needed) should be isolated (e.g. parentheses) and clearly marked as a translation; I would suggest: Python Module problem on Windows (Fr: Problème de module Python sur Windows)

Comment: I wrote tkinter but it doesn't work
and I tried to ask the question in French but they removed the French part

Comment: `tkinter` cannot be installed using `pip`.  It should be installed if you select it when installing Python.

Comment: ok but it's ok it works it was just an IDE problem. The problem is solved